# How to correctly use EF5's DbContext to get values using a SQL query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I've been trying to wrap my head around the correct way to use EF5's `DbContext` to query data using SQL. I am fully aware that EF is an ORM and would normally be used with linqTOentities and entity objects. But I have an interesting case requiring SQL.

Here's the sample code that I've been using:

```
testQuery = "select 'HITHERE' as firstval, 'HOTHERE' as secondval;";
var results = DataContext.Database.SqlQuery<string>(testQuery);
```

When I run the code above (C#) I get the following error:

```
{"The data reader has more than one field. Multiple fields are not valid for EDM primitive or enumeration types."}
```

I figured that the error had to do with the `string` part of `.SqlQuery<string>(testQuery)` not being the correct type to bind to. So I changed the code to this:

```
testQuery = "select 'HITHERE' as firstval, 'HOTHERE' as secondval;";
var results = DataContext.Database.SqlQuery<List<string>>(testQuery);
```

When I run this updated code, `results` has no values, count is 0. However, when I run the test sql query in SSMS I get what you would expect; one row, two values with columns names. firstVal = HITHERE and secondVal = HOTHERE.

How can I bind those select values to variables in C# with DbContext?

Comment: Typically you declare table objects and use LINQ to query them, rather than using a raw query, which is what make the EntityFramework useful

Comment: Oh, yes. Sorry I wasn't clear. I know that EF is an ORM and would typically be used that way. I have an edge case that requires executing a stored procedure that returns a series of values. I'd like to use EF to perform this query (if possible).

Comment: ah okay I misunderstood then

Comment: Maybe you better use classic ADO.Net or a tool like Dapper _besides_ EF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DataContext.Database.SqlQuery<string>(testQuery);` is expected a single string value **per row** so the following query would satisfy this setup

```
select 'HITHERE' as firstval
union
select 'HOTHERE' as secondval;";
```

for the query you are running you would need a class (or some type) with 2 string properties

```
public class resultsClass
{
    public string firstval { get; set; }
    public string secondval { get; set; }
}
```

and you can then do

```
var results = DataContext.Database.SqlQuery<resultsClass>(testQuery);
```

which should contain one result

---

UPDATE

Your example seems to contain key/value pairs - are you able to use this?

```
select 'firstValue', 'HITHERE'
union
select 'secondValue', 'HOTHERE'

public class resultsClass
{
    public string key { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}

var results = DataContext.Database.SqlQuery<resultsClass>(testQuery);
```

Comment: Is it possible to implement this using an anonymous type instead of `resultsClass`?

Comment: that's unlikely. You *could* return a `dynamic` type but it's really not a great decision. Another option is to return some sort of list of key/value pairs?

Comment: Thanks for the input. I was hoping to not have to create a brand new class just for this. But it seems that this answer is the straightest path to completing my objective. the key/value pair makes it more palatable because I might be able to reuse the class if I come across a similar situation in the future.

Comment: I get the same error, but I'm trying to execute a stored procedure. What type should I use for that? My query is: `use db;exec sys.sp_droprole @rolename`

Comment: @Akbari do you have the correct permissions to run that sp? What is the exact error message?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure about permission. I've changed the type to `<List<string>>`, and everything's fine now. Thanks for your attention Qujck.